# Array with 2 indexes not passing a conditional test on it's first index

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Why is a `cont[key].config.classes` value of `["photo"]` passing this test when a value of `["photo", "title_caption"]` is not?

```
if (cont[key].config.classes[0] == "photo") {
    console.log('this array passed: ' + cont[key].config.classes);
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Can you post a complete example the illustrates the problem? (Consult: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: As Mark said can you please explain more...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the lack of context, thought maybe there was something basic here we were missing. We'll take better care to ask more complete questions in the future. Turns out the data entry form for the object `cont` was leaving a carriage return at the end of the first index of `cont[key].config.classes[0]` in the second example. We realized this only after applying `JSON.stringify` to the object, and finding a trailing instance of `\r` at the end of the first index. (i.e. `["photo\r","title_caption"]` ) Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:

```
'photo' == ['photo'] // true
'photo' == ['photo', 'title_caption'] // false
```

Proof:

```js
const arr1 = ["photo"]

if (arr1 == "photo") {
  console.log('this array passed: ' + arr1);
} else {
  console.log('this array failed: ' + arr1);
}

const arr2 = ["photo", "title_caption"]

if (arr2 == "photo") {
  console.log('this array passed: ' + arr2);
} else {
  console.log('this array failed: ' + arr2);
}
```

Comment: I think you missed that we were checking for the value of `cont[key].config.classes[0]`, not the whole array `cont[key].config.classes`. Thanks for your response though. We figured it out, posted our solution below.